# How do I get a device's gateway in Unity?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, gateway

I'm trying to receive the standard gateway of the device in Unity and C# on an Android smartphone, but I just can't fix it.

That's the reason why I'm asking if there is a possibility to find a gateway on an Android smartphone using Unity and C#.

I already tried this one, which does work in the Unity editor:

```
    NetworkInterface[] adapters = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
    foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in adapters)
    {
        IPInterfaceProperties adapterProperties = adapter.GetIPProperties();
        GatewayIPAddressInformationCollection addresses = adapterProperties.GatewayAddresses;
        if (addresses.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (GatewayIPAddressInformation address in addresses)
            {
                if (address.Address.ToString() != "0.0.0.0")
                {
                    Debug.Log("Gateway: " + address.Address.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: See following webpages : http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/iphlpapi/GetAdaptersInfo.html and http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/IP_ADAPTER_INFO.html

Comment: There is one problem with this solution. The DLL can't be found in Android and if I want to add the DLL file as a reference, then Microsoft says that the reference could not be added, because it's maybe not accessible or a valid assembly/COM component. (So it only works on my desktop)

Comment: Try this webpage : http://www.codepool.biz/how-to-monitor-usb-events-on-android.html

Comment: I do get this error in adb logcat. Maybe that will help you a little bit out?
`I/Unity   (14783): EntryPointNotFoundException: getifaddrs
I/Unity   (14783):   at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Net.NetworkInformation.LinuxNetworkInterface:getifaddrs (intptr&)`

Comment: Entry Point not found means either the name is wrong or the method/function is not public (also static and/or extern).  Check function name getifaddrs to make sure it is correct including upper and lower case value.

Comment: Getifaddrs is a standard Android function (if I'm right), so that can't be the problem. I think the problem is GetAllNetworkInterfaces. It's a standard method from a standard .NET library. (System.Net.NetworkInformation)

Comment: See following webpage.  Look at answer 2 "the bug report is available here". http://stackoverflow.com/users/5015238/jdweng?tab=responses

Comment: Make sure you have all the latest updates.  Look like the problem has been fixed in most cases.  If you still have issues I would open new report at bugzilla (the link mentioned above).

Answer (score 1):

Create a `Network.java` file on `Assets/Plugins/Android` directory.

> Assets/Plugins/Android/Network.java

```
package com.mynet;
 
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
 
 
public class Network{
    //Match the IP of class C address
    public static final String regexCIp = "^192\\.168\\.(\\d{1}|[1-9]\\d|1\\d{2}|2[0-4]\\d|25\\d)\\.(\\d{1}|[1-9]\\d|1\\d{2}|2[0-4]\\d|25\\d)$";
    //Match a class A address
    public static final String regexAIp = "^10\\.(\\d{1}|[1-9]\\d|1\\d{2}|2[0-4]\\d|25\\d)\\.(\\d{1}|[1-9]\\d|1\\d{2}|2[0-4]\\d|25\\d)\\.(\\d{1}|[1-9]\\d|1\\d{2}|2[0-4]\\d|25\\d)$";
    //Match B address
    public static final String regexBIp = "^172\\.(1[6-9]|2\\d|3[0-1])\\.(\\d{1}|[1-9]\\d|1\\d{2}|2[0-4]\\d|25\\d)\\.(\\d{1}|[1-9]\\d|1\\d{2}|2[0-4]\\d|25\\d)$";
 
 
    public  String getHostIp() {
        String hostIp;
        Pattern ip = Pattern.compile("(" + regexAIp + ")|" + "(" + regexBIp + ")|" + "(" + regexCIp + ")");
        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> networkInterfaces = null;
        try {
            networkInterfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        InetAddress address;
        while (networkInterfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
            NetworkInterface networkInterface = networkInterfaces.nextElement();
            Enumeration<InetAddress> inetAddresses = networkInterface.getInetAddresses();
            while (inetAddresses.hasMoreElements()) {
                address = inetAddresses.nextElement();
                String hostAddress = address.getHostAddress();
                Matcher matcher = ip.matcher(hostAddress);
                if (matcher.matches()) {
                    hostIp = hostAddress;
                    return hostIp;
                }
 
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

> Use this script in `C#` code like below:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class MyIPScript: MonoBehaviour
{

    public Text ipText;

    public void Start()
    {
        string ip = GetIP();
        ipText.text = ip;
    }

    private string GetIP() {
        AndroidJavaObject jo = new AndroidJavaObject("com.mynet.Network");
        AndroidJavaClass act = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        return jo.Call<string>("getHostIp");
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** This will only work on `Android` devices. You will not see any IP address if you test it on your `PC`. So, build your unity project by selecting `Android` from `Build Settings` and generate `apk` file then install it on your `Android Phone` or `VR Headset`. I tested it on `Oculus Quest` and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Works in PC:

```
IPAddress GatewayAddress = NetworkInterface
                .GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
                .Where(n => n.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
                .Where(n => n.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback)
                .Where(n => n.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback)
                .SelectMany(n => n.GetIPProperties()?.GatewayAddresses)
                .Select(g => g?.Address)
                .Where(a => a != null)
                .Where(a => a.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                .FirstOrDefault();
```